# A complex sentence contained "as much...as..."

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have searched a lot about "as much as", so I knew what it basic means. But this sentence is hard to understand for me.

> To summarize, then, I suggest that we take Frege's ascription of a sense to a Proper Name to mean that not only must one think of an object-the referent of the term-in order to understand a sentence containing it, but also anyone who is to understand the sentence must think of the referent in the same particular way. **It is therefore, for Frege, as much a public and objective
> property of a term that it imposes this requirement, as that it has such and such an object as its referent.**
> Evans, G. 1982: The Varieties of Reference. Oxford: Oxford University Press,p.17.

My question is what is the bold sentence mean? Is it mean that the amount of a terms' property is equal to the amount of object? I can't understand, and I am aprreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the meaning, but I can understand the grammar.

Frege says that a term has two 'public and objective properties'. The fact of 'imposing this requirement' (stated in the previous sentence) is just **as much** a property of the term as the fact of 'having such and such an object as its referent'.